# How to display image from paginated JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm new to JSON and jQuery. I just tried sample from this site http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/  to display photo from Flickr and it's work.

Then I try to display photo from my friend's site. But it isn't work anymore.

Here is structure of the JSON data. I've found there's pagination here. But I don't know how I should do to refer LargePhotoUrl to display

```
{
featuredshops: [],
-page: {
    - pageInformation: {
        number: 1,
        size: 20
    }
    first: 1,
    last: 20,
    totalNumberOfPages: 10,
    totalNumberOfEntities: 100
    - entities: [
        -{
            id: 1,
            name: "A",
            -photos{
                - smallPhotoUrl: "photos/1/smalldisplay.jpg"
                - largePhotoUrl: "photos/1/largedisplay.jpg"
            }
        }
        -{
            id: 2,
            name: "B",
            -photos{
                - smallPhotoUrl: "photos/2/smalldisplay.jpg"
                - largePhotoUrl: "photos/2/largedisplay.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

And This's what I've tried

```
function() {
        var shopAPI = "www.sample.com/shops.json";
        $.getJSON( shopAPI, {
        format: "json"
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $.each(data.page.entities, function(i, item){
            var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", item.photos.largePhotoUrl);
            $("<a/>").attr({href: item.photos.largePhotoUrl, title: "Shop Photos"}).append(img).appendTo("#images");
        });
    });
})()
```